# Java > 8 stream count multiple items at the same time

Tags: java, filter, count, java-8, java-stream

I have a very large list of objects and I want to count number of objects based on one of their attribute. what I have right now is:

```
long low = myList.stream().filter(p -> p.getRate().equals("Low")).count(); 
long medium = myList.stream().filter(p -> p.getRate().equals("Medium")).count();    
long high = myList.stream().filter(p -> p.getRate().equals("High")).count();
```

I am not sure how Java 8 handles this but I am worried about performances! Is there anyway so I can count these 3 attributes in one call? in order to improve performance?

Something so that it returns a Map or list of object.

Comment: How would you do it with a for loop? Why wouldn't you do the same with a stream? Before optimizing, have you **measured** and proven a performance problem?

Comment: with loop I just iterate over all items and check the value of getRate() and update the value of map with specific key, and no I didn't measure the performance.

Comment: Why use a Map when you could use an object with three fields? Start by measuring.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can group your `List` by the rate of each object and count the number of occurences. Assuming your object are of type `MyClass`:

```
Map<String, Long> map = myList.stream().collect(groupingBy(MyClass::getRate, counting()));
```

This will return a `Map` where the key is the rate and the value is the number of elements from the list having that rate. Then, it is simply a matter of getting the `"Low"`, `"Medium"` and `"High"` keys.

[`groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is a collector that groups elements according to the given classifier (here, it is `MyClass::getRate`) and performs a reduction on the values using the downstream collector (here, it is [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--)).

NB: the following static imports are needed for the code to compile:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```